# How do change the dotnet.exe version used by a private VSTS build agent

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have created a private VSTS build agent that tries to build my .net core project. I've installed the latest version of the .net core SDK on the build machine, but when I kick off a build it tries to use the version of the dotnet.exe installed in the agent build folder (c:\agent\bin\dotnet.exe), rather than the newly installed version in c:\Program Files\dotnet...

Is there any way to tell the build definition where to look for the latest dotnet.exe?

**UPDATE** I just restarted the build agent service and all seems fine now,

Comment: So it used the newly installed dotnet.exe now? If you solve the problem, you can give it as answer and mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Comment: Yes, it now uses the new dotnet.exe, unfortunately I don't seem to be able to mark my question as the answer.

Comment: Yeah, comments can't be marked. You can write it in answer and mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my update above, restarting the build agent fixed the problem. The build agent now uses the latest version of dotnet.exe.